# Neo4j Duplicating Relationships with Match Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have the following graph:

[image: neo]

In the bottom left corner there is a small triangle of nodes. Between 2 nodes there is a double relationship (i.e. relationship from nodeA to nodeB and a relationship from nodeB to nodeA).

All the relationships have GUIDs as one of their properties. Now I am trying to select those 2 relationships and return the data but whenever I do so I get duplicates to node IDs that don't exist. It's almost as if Neo4j deleted the node but kept remnants of it's long ID value.

I tried this query:

```
MATCH ()-[relationship1]-() 
WHERE relationship1.id IN ['9eb0eb49-8cfe-4749-98bb-8077a059c3e1','eec0efe2-b924-407b-ac05-1cd00e94b581']
RETURN DISTINCT relationship1
```

I also tried to give the relationships directionality with this query:

```
MATCH ()-[relationship1]->() 
WHERE relationship1.id IN ['9eb0eb49-8cfe-4749-98bb-8077a059c3e1','eec0efe2-b924-407b-ac05-1cd00e94b581']
RETURN DISTINCT relationship1
```

Both times I get this data:

```
[
  {
    "relationship1": {
      "identity": 435,
      "start": 347,
      "end": 349,
      "type": "unitTestRelationship",
      "properties": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-30T00:01:00+02:00",
        "systemId": "00 00001 2020 0 0",
        "id": "9eb0eb49-8cfe-4749-98bb-8077a059c3e1",
        "testNumber": 1011
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "relationship1": {
      "identity": 434,
      "start": 349,
      "end": 347,
      "type": "unitTestRelationship",
      "properties": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-30T00:01:00+02:00",
        "systemId": "00 00001 2020 0 0",
        "id": "eec0efe2-b924-407b-ac05-1cd00e94b581",
        "testNumber": 2005
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "relationship1": {
      "identity": 467,
      "start": 363,
      "end": 362,
      "type": "unitTestRelationship",
      "properties": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-30T00:01:00+02:00",
        "systemId": "00 00001 2020 0 0",
        "id": "eec0efe2-b924-407b-ac05-1cd00e94b581",
        "testNumber": 2005
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "relationship1": {
      "identity": 468,
      "start": 362,
      "end": 363,
      "type": "unitTestRelationship",
      "properties": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-12-30T00:01:00+02:00",
        "systemId": "00 00001 2020 0 0",
        "id": "9eb0eb49-8cfe-4749-98bb-8077a059c3e1",
        "testNumber": 1011
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So the data shows duplicates, but then if I just run a MATCH query for all the nodes and relationships I get that the relationship IDs should be (467, 468) and the node IDs should be (362, 363).

So where are the first 2 JSON records coming from?

Comment: Try `MATCH p = ()-[relationship1]-() 
WHERE relationship1.id IN ['9eb0eb49-8cfe-4749-98bb-8077a059c3e1','eec0efe2-b924-407b-ac05-1cd00e94b581']
RETURN p` in the browser to see the resulting nodes

Comment: What do you get when you run this?
MATCH (n1)-[r]-(n2)
WHERE id(n1) = 347 and id(n2) = 349.
RETURN n1, n2, r

Comment: Please show, in your question, the query that leads you to believe there are no duplicates.

Comment: Hi all, so before I tried these queries I updated to v3.5.14. I couldn't update to v4 because I still need to use Graph algorithms which aren't yet supported on v4. This resolved the issues. Then my first query worked correctly and only returned the 2 relationships. Apologies as I should have done this first.